# Ionic Framework - detect if the device is rooted/jailbroken

Tags: ionic-framework, jailbreak

I want to detect if the device is rooted/jailbroken using Ionic Framework.
I am using iRoot plugin for the same.

It works fine but if the user has installed JailProtect app he can block my app from detecting the rooted device.
Is there any better plugin than iRoot which will be difficult to bypass

Comment: Hi, Jailbreak developer here. :) Sorry to say, but I think if some software can bypass iOS' security, bypassing a detection plugin won't be too hard either.